# offline GTFS connection from A to B

Tags: sql, sqlite, gtfs

The project I am working on involves static offline GTFS data in a mobile app. All the GTFS data is available inside realm-objects (or SQLite if needed).

Now, I would like to establish all train- or bus-connections from A to B (starting after a certain departure-time).

How do I query the GTFS-data in order to get a connection from A to B ???

I reealized to get all trips leaving from A.
I realized to get all station-names along that trip including times.

But I find it very hard to get the connection information between two locations A and B. What SQL queries do i have to set up in order to get that information ?

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

**If you just want to dynamically calculate shortest travel routes between static hubs, in an offline application, determined like the following image, you can use the following formula:**

[image: Source: Wikipedia: DijkstraDemo.gif]  [image: Random formulas from Shortest Path Problem] <sub>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Definition))</sub>

---

### Here's the pseudo code:

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      create vertex set Q
 4
 5      for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
 6          dist[v] ← INFINITY                  // Unknown distance from source to v
 7          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                 // Previous node in optimal path from source
 8          add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
 9
10      dist[source] ← 0                        // Distance from source to source
11      
12      while Q is not empty:
13          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Node with the least distance
14                                                      // will be selected first
15          remove u from Q 
16          
17          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
18              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
19              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
20                  dist[v] ← alt 
21                  prev[v] ← u 
22
23      return dist[], prev[]
```

<sub>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm))</sub>

---

**Alright, I'll admit so far my answer was a *tad* facetious...**

I suspect you don't realize ***just how complicated*** it is to do what you're asking, especially in an offline environment.  Companies like Google and Microsoft have spent millions on research with huge teams of data scientists.

If this is something you are serious about, I'd encourage you to start with a 10×10 grid and work on the logic of getting from *"Point A → Point B"* when you start adding barriers in random places (this simulating roads beginning & ending).  Recently I was surprised how complicated a *seemingly-simple, somewhat-related* Stack Overflow "pipe sizes conversion" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47028610/8112776) that I answered had become.

**If you didn't have the "offline" condition**, I would've suggested looking into getting a [free] API Key for [Google Web Services Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). Basically you tell it a where Points A & B are, and it gives you detailed route information, via transit or other methods.

Another of Google's many API's that could be helpful is the [Snap to Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap), which turns partial or error-ridden paths into driveable ones.

The study ***Route Logic*** and ***Shortest Path Logic*** is actually ***really fascinating stuff***, and there are some amazing resources to learn about the related theories (see below), including a [video from Google](https://youtu.be/-0ErpE8tQbw) explaining how they went about it.

...but unfortunately this isn't something that's going to be accomplished with a simple *SQL Query*.

---

## *Actual* Resources:

- YouTube : [Google Tech Talk: Fast Route Planning](https://youtu.be/-0ErpE8tQbw)
- Wikipedia : [Shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)
- Wikipedia : [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

---

### ...and some *slightly* Lighter Reading:

- Wikipedia : [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)
- [Why UPS drivers don’t turn left and you probably shouldn’t either](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/why-ups-drivers-don-t-turn-left-and-you-probably-shouldn-t-either-a7541241.html)
- Google Web Services : [Directions API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)
- Stack Overflow : [Shortest Route of converters between two different pipe sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47028610/8112776)
- Wikipedia : [Seven Bridges of Königsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg)

Comment: ...weird, I actually thought this question was over on the [Stack Exchange GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gtfs) page with a [tag:gtfs] tag when I answered it, which somehow made it seem *more* unrealistic of a question than I interpreted it at...  Nonetheless, @iKK I hope I didn't come across as a jerk -- for all I know I might have misinterpreted your question completely.  I do think it's an interesting field of study...  but damn complicated too!